# jQuery: Uncaught ReferenceError: π is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I absolutely have no idea why this error happen when loading jquery. I use Chrome Version 65. It also used to work before and it should not throw error like this so it's very confusing too me.

Here is just my HTML code:

```
<script src="./assets/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

My console log:

[image]

When clicking on line 612:

[image]

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: The problem is because there's a `π` character in the value of `data`, presumably in one of the keys of the object in the JSON.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with jQuery itself. Something is evaluating code (seems to be an Ajax call) and the code is invalid.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, no, it isn't. @GreatAnswer,  you should post what `data` is. Obviusly not valid JavaScript, but we'd like to see it. And posting the jQuery code is not useful at all.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that it is because the jquery tried to load d3.js but the d3 source code has been formatted by my code editor so it broke (due to such characters like "pi" inside d3.js). I downloaded d3.js again without touching it this time, then everything worked like expected.